# C++ read from class by its pointer and offset

Tags: c++, pointers, reverse-engineering, offset, disassembly

Ida pro generates this line in pseudo-code, and I have working class pointer and reverse engineered class, but I don't want to read something directly from class file.

Example in IDA Pro:

```
*(_DWORD *)(v3 + 9649) = 1;

// Alignment: 1
class CVehicle
{
    DWORD modelid; // 0
    float pos[3]; // 4
    WORD player; // 16
}

CVehicle *pVehicle;
```

I know, if I want to get player, then I need to do that:

```
pVehicle->player
```

But what if I want to get player by offset? Because sometime I need to read by offset because I didn't reverse engineered the complete class. Example

```
*(WORD*)(pVehicle + 16) // That should work, should return player, but will crash. Why?
```

Comment: What's the type of `pVehicle`? Do you know how pointer arithmetic works?

Comment: incrementing a pointer to CVehicle will change memory offset by multiples of the size of CVehicle, not the number of bytes. You are getting a segfault probably because you are accessing memory that doesn't belong to you outside of the class. To get what you are after you need to be using `char*` and explicit casts and be wary since you are going to break the aliasing rules.

Comment: Oh, understood. But, then how I can do that, which IDA says?

This method with CVehicle class

Example, there v3 is the pointer and 9649 is the variable offset within the class which will be set to 1.
*(_DWORD *)(v3 + 9649) = 1;

Comment: I haven't ever done this before, but if you reinterpret cast to `char*`, then do your byte offset, then reinterpret cast to `WORD*` and compile with strict aliasing off, then it could work. `*(WORD*)(((char*)pVehicle) + 16)`

Comment: Just replace it as soon as it is feasible. It will be extremely difficult to ensure that it will always work robustly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand what you're saying in your posting, this is how I'd do it:

Header:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
class CPlayer
{
public:
    unsigned char Unknown00[9649];
    char Unknown9649;
};

class CVehicle
{
public:
    DWORD modelid; // 0
    float pos[3]; // 4
    CPlayer *pPlayer; // 16
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Code:

```
char SomethingIWant;
CVehicle *pVehicle; // set previously
CPlayer *pPlayer = nullptr;

if (pVehicle)
   pPlayer = pVehicle->pPlayer;
if (pPlayer)
   SomethingIWant = pPlayer->Unknown9649;
```

Then, you can just fill in the classes as you go and discover more information.

(Disclaimer:  The code above assumes that pVehicle->pPlayer is either nullptr or valid.  Otherwise, more code would be needed to properly verify that pPlayer is valid.)